# Delete a line if the column have content

Tags: excel

I'm working on a spread sheet, and i just want to know how i delete a line with the column have a content.

Example:

LINE 1: WORK

LINE 2: WORK

LINE 3:

I have 3 lines, but only in line 1 and 2 the first column have content ("WORK") and the third line don't have nothing.

I want to find a way to delete the lines with content in the first column.

Someone?

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteNonBlanks()

Dim i           As Long
Dim lr          As Long
Dim wb          As Workbook
Dim ws          As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook '' whatever workbook you need
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) '' whatever sheet you need

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '' last row

For i = lr To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        ws.Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

To explain this a bit more:

You identify the bottom row in the range you need to check, then you iterate over it backwards, testing the value of each row's first column. If the value is not blank you delete that row.

To explain why you need it to go backwards imagine the example you provided, (the first two rows have content in them and the third row is blank). Now combine that with my example of iterating over it, except this time going from 1 to the last row.

Your first iteration is the first row, it notices there's values there, deletes that row. Now everything beneath it moves up one row (row 2 becomes row 1, row 3 becomes row 2, so on and so forth). Our iteration is now looking at row 2. With the data in row 2 moving to row 1, it now won't be evaluated and that row won't be deleted.

Hope this helps.